# Tableau error: Invalid expression, cannot be unaggregated

Tags: tableau-api

I've created a tableau TDE file that I've been using regularly-  now when I when doing a totally normal data query the view data icon then hit the "underlying data" tab I get the error message
"An error occurred while loading the data"  an offers a "show details" button.
When that button is selected I get: Invalid expression, cannot be unaggregated- anyone know why this is happening?

[image: error when requesting underlying data]

[image: Shown details of previous error]

Answer (score 0):

digging on the tableausoftware.com forum, I found that sets could lead to this error.  I had just created a couple of sets in my workbook prior to this issue.   Once the sets were deleted- things worked again.  I was able to see the underlying data.